# Как убрать в pug компиляцию инлайновых тегов в одну строку?

Tags: gulp, pug

Здравствуйте можно как то сделать что бы pug не компилировал инлайновые теги в одну строку
в gulp включен (pretty: true)

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item"><a class="link" href="#">vk</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a class="link" href="#">tw</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a class="link" href="#">fb</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: pretty: true как раз для этого и нужен. Разве не помог?